# If statement not looping

Tags: c++, file, file-io

I had this working yesterday and for some reason it has stopped, what I'm trying to do is when a user types the command "ADD" followed by first name, last name, and phone number it appends that to a file. What was working is after the command executes it would let me type "ADD" fname, lname, phone again, and increment the counter writing all of it to the file it would let me does this till I manually killed the program, and every entry would be in the text file. Now it will accept the command more than once, however it will only write to the file the first entry i type in.

Is anyone able to spot what i'm missing?

```
"server.c" [dos] 200L, 5323Cc
/*
 * server.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define SERVER_PORT 1617
#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define MAX_LINE 512

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{

struct sockaddr_in sin;
socklen_t addrlen;


char buf[MAX_LINE];
int len;
int s;
int new_s;
int r = 1000;
int result;
char message;
FILE *file_ptr;
string cmd, fn, ln, ph;
string add = "ADD";
string del = "DELETE";
string list = "LIST";
string quite = "QUIT";
string shutdown = "SHUTDOWN";



/* build address data structure */
bzero ((char *) &sin, sizeof (sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port = htons (SERVER_PORT);

/* setup passive open */
if ((s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
 {
  perror ("socket");
  exit (1);
}

if ((bind (s, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (sin))) < 0)
{
  perror ("bind");
  exit (1);
}

listen (s, MAX_PENDING);

addrlen = sizeof (sin);
cout << "The server is up, waiting for connection" << endl;


  /* wait for connection, then receive and print text */
while (1)
{
  if ((new_s = accept (s, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, &addrlen)) < 0)
    { 
      perror ("accept");
      exit (1);
    }
  cout << "new connection from " << inet_ntoa (sin.sin_addr) << endl;

  while (len = recv (new_s, buf, sizeof (buf), 0))
    {
      /*send (new_s, buf, strlen(buf) + 1, 0);  original send to echo in client */

    /* create string stream from contents of buffer */
      stringstream stream (buf);

    /* read user input from string stream into strings for user input */
      stream >> cmd;
      stream >> fn;
      stream >> ln;
      stream >> ph;



  /* create character arrays and copy strings into character arrays */
      char command[9] = "        ";
      char fname[9] = "        ";
      char lname[9] = "        ";
      char phone[13] = "            ";

      cmd.copy (command, 8);
      fn.copy (fname, 8);
      ln.copy (lname, 8);
      ph.copy (phone, 12);




 /* determine if valid command received */
      /* Adds whatever follows the word "ADD" to the text file" */
      if (cmd.compare (add) == 0){
     {
          file_ptr = fopen ("file1.txt", "a+");
          fprintf (file_ptr, "%d" "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s", r, " ", fname,
                   lname, phone);
          fprintf (file_ptr, "\n");
          fclose(file_ptr);
          ++r;
        }
    }
/* LIST user input */
      else if (cmd.compare (list) == 0)
        {
          file_ptr = fopen ("file1.txt", "r");

          size_t count;
          while ((count = fread (buf, 1, sizeof buf, file_ptr)) > 0)
            {
              send (new_s, buf, count, 0);
              fclose (file_ptr);
            }
        }

      else if (cmd.compare (del) == 0)      /*Delete user input */
        {
          {
            FILE *fp1, *fp2;
            /*consider 40 character string to store filename */
            char filename[40];
            char c;
            int del_line, temp = 1;
            fp1 = fopen ("file1.txt", "r");
            c = getc (fp1);
            while (c != EOF)
              {
                printf ("%c", c);
                /*print current character and read next character */
                c = getc (fp1);
              }
            rewind (fp1);
            printf (" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:");
            /*accept number from user. */
            scanf ("%d", &del_line);


            fp2 = fopen ("copy.c", "w");
            c = getc (fp1);
            while (c != EOF)
              {
                c = getc (fp1);
                if (c == '\n')
                  temp++;


                if (temp != del_line)
                  {
                    /*copy all lines in file copy.c */
                    putc (c, fp2);
                  }
              }

            fclose (fp1);
            fclose (fp2);
            /*remove original file */
            remove ("file1.txt");
            /*rename the file copy.c to original name */
            rename ("copy.c", "file1.txt");
            printf
              ("\n The contents of file after being modified are as  follows:\n");
            fp1 = fopen ("file1.txt", "r");
            c = getc (fp1);
            while (c != EOF)
              {
                printf ("%c", c);
                c = getc (fp1);
              }
            fclose (fp1);

          }
        }
      else
        {
          cout << "Invalid Command" << endl;
        }

    }
  close (new_s);
}
}
```

Comment: An `if` statement is not supposed to loop.

Comment: In which programming language `if` statement used for loop?

Comment: Perhaps there is an outer loop, but what does `if (cmd.compare (add) == 0)` do? Where is `add` anything to do with the data?

Comment: Maybe I miss titled it then, it should allow me to input a command and execute against it multiple times though.

Added rest of code for clarification

Comment: Need declarations for `cmd`, `fn`, `ln`, and `ph`.  What does the `copy` method do?

Comment: Where is the `add` variable initialized, and what is its type?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using C style I/O to the console but C++ I/O with the buffer (and stringstream)?  I suggest you be consistent and choose one or the other.

Comment: The `r` variable is not used, you can get rid of it or show us code where it is used (in other words, edit your post with the code).

Comment: Finally: when you used the debugger, which statements are causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables before and after the statement is executed?

Comment: Please post a complete program which can be compiled and run. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Added the rest of the code

Comment: In a couple of places you have double nested braces like `if (some expression) { { some code } }`. Is there a reason for that or is it a weird typo?

Comment: I've been moving things like "return 0;" and the close(new_s); 

to different locations trying to get it to work, they are left over from all the moving

Comment: You're shuffling code around instead of using a debugger or trying to understand what you've written? Wasn't the error in your last question caused by the same random code shuffling technique?

Comment: Indeed it was, unfortunately I was handed half the code.. the part that handles the sockets, and I am supposed to build an address book out of it. The instructor built the thing using both C and C++ library's. So no I don't fully understand sockets or even what part of this program is doing. I'm just trying my hardest to meet the objectives of the assignment. I am also working with a partner who is coding parts of this, so things are being copy pasted in and out of the program, which is why indenting and all that is jacked beyond belief.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide a valid solution without a wholesale rewrite of OP's code because this program is too broken. Instead, here are a few notes:

```
while (len = recv (new_s, buf, sizeof (buf), 0))
```

Will assign the recv return code to len and then test len. If len is 0, it exits the loop. If len is any other value, including recv's return value of -1 on error, the loop continues.

The handing of a socket error is functionally identical to this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int test;
    while (test = -1)
    {
        std::cout << "loop de ";
    }
}
```

And that is not good.

TCP/IP does not deliver nice, clean packets because it is a streaming protocol. This is beaten to death elsewhere so I'm not going to cover it or look for links. Google does a great job on that front.

Because TCP/IP is a stream, recv will give you whatever data it has, up to the size of the given buffer. If it has nothing, it will wait for something to arrive.

This means you might get several messages in one recv or only a few bytes. Since the message may be cut off in the middle, there might not even be a terminating null in buf which turns this:

```
stringstream stream (buf);
```

into a mystery grab-bag. You will have no clue what's inside stream. Since OP is not inspecting and handling the return from recv, they could wind up reprocessing the last contents of buf over and over because recv returned an error code and no data.

stream >> cmd;

And its fellow stream reads may or may not succeed and because they are not tested, OP will never know. Once one fails, the rest of the reads will fail because the stream's error state is not cleared.

These:

```
cmd.copy (command, 8);
```

Will not null terminate properly. They do not write far enough into the char array to write over the null placed into the last element by the way they were initialized so the fprintfs that follow will survive, but not print the correct result.

So given the above minefield, the output not being correct is no surprise and not worth trying to provide a solution.

OP needs to do some reading on and practicing with socket programming and standard streams before continuing with this program.